# How to add animation on ViewPager item remove in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am using view pager as a card slider. Now there is a requirement that we can delete any card but there should be animation in deletion as we have in recycler view.

How can we achieve this in ViewPager?

*Note: This is a question where I don't need to post my current code so I didn't add any code.*